# Which database design approach is best, both options have limitations I can't find a solution for

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, php-7

**Background:**
I'm building an online tool where I store and analyze form entries (MySQL 8.x).
An entry contains multiple questions (nr of questions can vary per form).
Table will contain between 1 million to 50 million rows, depending on the 2 methods below and # of entries.

**Problem:**
Getting stuck at how to best design the schema of the feedback data table.

**Approach 1:**
1 entire entry is 1 row (preferred)
The table has these columns:

id (primary, ai), 
form_id (int), 
entry_id (int), 
form_questions (json column), 
form_answers (json column),
-This json column also contains the form_questiontype (see approach 2 for details),
About 6 other analytics related columns which I dont want to store in another table.

Benefits of this approach:

- I can easily do a select with a limit. Limit 0,100 will give me 100 full entries
- I can easily see how many entries a form has by looking at the nr of rows
- More efficient to delete 1 entire entry

Cons:

- The design is flat. So doing analytics on the answers is very slow because I can't do a full text index search/json column is slow
- Updating 1 answer can be a pain, but might be doable because it's a json column where a specific key can be targeted.

**Approach 2:**
Store every answer/question in 1 row (aka feedback data) **+ 1 row with some analytics data (aka header)**.
So if an entry has 10 questions, we will get 11 rows.

The table has these columns:

id (primary, ai), form_id (int), 
entry_id (int), 
form_question (varchar), 
form_answer (varchar, full text index),
form_questiontype (tinyint),
The questiontype is important, it is an integer where a specific nr. represents a specific question type.
For example, 1=input field, 2=nps score, 3=rating etc
So if I want to know the average NPS score I can add the form_questiontype in the where clause so I can avoid full table scan.

Benefits of this approach:

- I can more easily do efficient indexed queries with full text index options
- I can update/delete a specific answer very easily

Cons:

- Will generate MUCH more rows then approach 1.
- Selecting data with a limit will return partial entries.
- Deleting an entry means deleting 10+ rows instead of 1. When deleting 10.000 entries this will add up query time.

Biggest con is that if I do a select with a limit of 0,100, I don't get 100 entries, I get like 10 entries and some answers might not be included because the limit is based on rows, not 100 full entries.

I can target the header row, which will give me the possibility to do a limit (because 1 header row per entry). But the problem here is that I have to do another query in a PHP while loop to get the actual feedback data.

Hope you can help.

Comment: "So if an entry has 10 questions, we will get 11 rows." -- Why 11? That should be 10, shouldn't it?

Comment: No, we also have the header row (10 rows + 1 header row = 11). See "+ 1 row with some analytics data (aka header)."

Comment: What do you mean by header row? Tables in relational databases aren't spread sheets. They don't need a header row. The name of the columns is already given by the schema definition. Something seems to be wrong in your train of thoughts here...

Comment: I'll explain. The "header" row is just a row like the answer/question rows, but just contains some extra analytics data. So 10 answer/question rows + 1 "header" row = 1 entry

Comment: Still not got it a 100% but I am quite sure that doesn't belong there. As I understand, there's one such "header" per form and it isn't a question/answer. Put that as extra columns into the table where the forms are stored.

Comment: They are stored in the table where the form answer data is stored. The extra row is part of the form entry. It is kind of an answer, it contains stuff like viewport, os, device etc. It's just silly to store that information in every row, so therefore the 1 extra row\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends very heavily on your anticipated usage, and the completeness of your domain model.

In general terms, storing data as JSON in a database is good if you can't model the problem domain in advance (e.g. you aren't sure about what types of question you're going to ask in your surveys), or if the domain isn't neatly modelled in relational terms.

Using a relational model is good if you can be reasonably certain you understand the domain model at development time, and thee domain lends itself well to the relational model.

You concerns about "how many rows do I need to query" or "I might have to delver 10K rows" are largely irrelevant - a data model with appropriate indexes will easily handle this without noticeable performance problems.

Assuming you'll want to reason about surveys ("how many surveys have answers to every question?", "how many respondents rated question 6 at 6/10 or better?"), I'd say the JSON option is a very poor fit.

Your model is probably something like:

```
Survey
------
Survey_id (PK)
name
....

Survey_question
--------------
Survey_question_id (PK)
survey_id (fk)
Title
question_type


Survey_response
-----------
survey_response_id (pk)
survey_id (fk)
user_id (fk)
date
...

survey_response_answer
------------
survey_response_answer_id (pk)
survey_response_id (fk)
Survey_question_id (fk)
answer *
```

- Modelling the answers is tricky. Presumably, you have several answer types - numerical and text, perhaps date. I would keep it simple by having one column in "survey_response_answer" for each type of response (so "answer_numerical", "answer_text").

To get all the answers for a single survey, you have two options: two queries (one to get the `Survey_response` IDs, and one to get the matching `survey_response_answer` entries. This avoids retrieving lots of duplicated data from the Survey_response table.

The other option is to do it in a single query with a few joins:

```
select *
from Survey_response sr
inner join survey_response_answer sra
  on sr.survey_response_id = sra.survey_response__id
```

The "join" method will be quicker (all things being equal, one query with a join will be n times faster than 1 query for header data and n queries for details data), but you may need to trim out the header data that you don't need.

Comment: He Neville, Thanks! I was tempted to use JSON beause it could might be a NoSQL db like MongoDB replacement. In MongoDB approach 1 could probably work?

As it's a SaaS service, I create 1 entry table per customer (for more security, speed, optional customization etc). So 1000 tables when I have 1000 customers. If I follow your design this will be 2000 (the first 2 tables are already in the db).

The answer table already has a date column, forgot to mention that.
The problem is that I'll more need to do a select within the answers table then the survey_response table.

Comment: So with your answer, I need to do the same as in the answer of Sergio?
Select all id's first, then do a IN clause?

Answer (score 1):

> I can target the header row, which will give me the possibility to do a limit (because 1 header row per entry). But the problem here is that I have to do another query in a PHP while loop to get the actual feedback data.

Don't do N+1 queries then. Do two queries.

```
header_ids = select id from headers limit 10
feedback_rows = select * from feedback where header_id in header_ids
```

Then group feedback_rows in the app land.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean with header_id?. As I understand your answer you mean something like: $header_ids = select entry_id from results_table where specific_header_column=1.

Then do:
$feedback_rows = select * from results_table where entry_id IN $header_ids

This might work with a limit of 100. But what if the limit is 10.000 (for example for export to Excel).
Can you add 10.000 id's in a IN clause? And what about performance?

Comment: @Ralph: why store metadata (analytics and whatnot) in the same table/structure with questions/answers? Should be two different tables, if you ask me. But yes, that's what it means. You should be able to add 10k ids in an IN clause, but if not, you can always batch by 1000 or something. Performance-wise it will be orders of magnitude better than 10k individual queries.

Comment: "Should be two different tables,"Well, it's a SaaS service, so let's say 1000 people sign up. I don't want to add everything to 1 big entry table (for security, speed, custom options and other reasons) so I create 1 entry table per customer. So 1000 customers means 1000 tables. So just creating a meta table will give me 2000 tables.. The meta data is just about 6 columns and only the "header" row will contains this info (so no duplicate content)

Comment: @Ralph: "and only the "header" row will contains this info (so no duplicate content)" - not quite. The entry rows still will waste some disk/RAM space on storing empty values for those columns.

Comment: 1000 or 2000 tables - it makes no practical difference. Still linear growth. MySQL does not have a limit on number of tables.

Comment: "The entry rows still will waste some disk/RAM space on storing empty values for those columns" True ;)

However, with approach 2, not having this "header" row means that I have no way to select 1 entry, I will have to do a group by entry_id and then use that as "id" in the IN clause

Comment: @Ralph: unless you store "headers" with the metadata in another table, like suggested in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following sketch seems appropriate:

A table for the forms:

```
CREATE TABLE form
             (id integer AUTO INCREMENT,
              ...
              PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

A table for the questions:

```
CREATE TABLE question
             (id integer AUTO INCREMENT,
              form integer,
              ...
              PRIMARY KEY (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (form)
                          REFERENCES form
                                     (id)
                          ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

- A foreign key to the table for the forms determines to which form a question belongs.

A table for the sessions:

```
CREATE TABLE session
             (id integer AUTO INCREMENT,
              ...
              PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

- Your metadata goes here.

A table for the answers:

```
CREATE TABLE answer
             (id integer AUTO INCREMENT,
              question integer,
              session integer,
              ...
              PRIMARY KEY (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (question)
                          REFERENCES question
                                     (id)
                          ON DELETE CASCADE,
              FOREIGN KEY (session)
                          REFERENCES session
                                     (id)
                          ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

- A foreign key to the table for the question determines which question was answered.
- A foreign key to the table for the sessions determines in which session the question was answered.

To address multiple tenants, you could use one schema/database per tenant (maybe cleaner/easier to isolate/secure) or have the tenant's ID in every table as a foreign key to a tenant table.

Comment: Hi, except for the session table, I already have the other tables. The table I mentioned in the description is the answer table. so I have to do an IN clause?

Comment: @Ralph: Look into joins. They're likely superior to using `IN` in terms of performance and ease of use and can do (at least most of) what you apparently want to do.